# Differentiation to tangent and normals

Tags: calculus

The equation of the curve is given by

$ y = \frac{6}{2x^2+1} $

Find the equation of the tangent and the normal at the point when

$ x = -1$

My workings

When $x= -1, y= 2 $

$\frac{d}{dx} (Y) = \frac{-24}{(2x^2+1)^2} $

Sub $x=-1$ to the above expression to find the gradient ...

$\frac{d}{dx} (Y) = \frac{-8}{3} $

Now , to find the equation of the tangent , what can I do ?

Is it $y=mx+c$ ? 
Sub in $x=-1 , y=2$ to find the y intercept and then continue to find the equation of the tangent ?

Which is

$y=  \frac{-8}{3} x - \frac{2}{3} $

But that don't feel right to me .. so im here to ask .

Answer (score 3):

The derivative should be

$\frac{d}{dx} (Y) = \frac{-24*x}{(2x^2+1)^2} $

when $x=-1 $, it gives $24/9 $

So the tangent equation is $ y-2=8/3 *(x+1) $ and the normal is $ y-2 =-3/8 *(x+1)$

Does it sound good ?

Comment: How did the $y-2$ and $(x+1)$ come about

Comment: @user307640  If you want the tangent at point (x=a,y=b), you must write $ y-b = y'(a)*(x-a) $. If $x=a$, you find well $y=b$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent#Equations

Answer (score 1):

HINT: write your function in the form $$y=6(2x^2+1)^{-1}$$ then the derivative is given by
$$y'=6(-1)(2x^2+1)^{-2}\cdot 4x=\frac{-24x}{(2x^2+1)^2}$$

Comment: ya missed a negative bro